# br-ex and floating ips not accessible

Tags: networking, juju, maas, openstack, openstack-autopilot

I have an Autopilot deployed Openstack configuration it is deployed without error and all services are up acording to juju status. I am new and although I have blow away and redeployed MAAS and LDS several time I still get a bit lost.  My setup is as followings

MAAS 
eth0: gets IP via DHCP from Internet router to ISP 1
eth1: Private network 10.1.1.10/24 managed and providing DHCP/DNS
eth1.10 10.1.10.10/24 unmanaged
eth1.12 10.1.12.10/24 unmanaged
eth1.50 10.1.50.10/24 umanaged with gateway set to 10.1.50.1 (this vlan on the layer3 switch is connected to ISP 2 to be used for instance public access)

Landscape Node (Bootstrap Node)
eth0: PXE boot from MAAS private network
eth1: Unconfigured but in same fabric as eth0
eth1.10 network 10.1.10.0/24 ip unconfigured
eth1.12 network 10.1.12.0/24 ip unconfigured
eth1.50 network 10.1.50.0/24 ip unconfigured

Network Node
eth0: PXE boot from MAAS private network
eth1: Unconfigured but in same fabric as eth0
eth1.10 network 10.1.10.0/24 ip unconfigured
eth1.12 network 10.1.12.0/24 ip unconfigured
eth1.50 network 10.1.50.0/24 ip static 10.1.50.2 (verified can ping default GW for ISP 2)

Compute Nodes 1-3
eth0: PXE boot from MAAS private network
eth1: Unconfigured but in same fabric as eth0
eth1.10 network 10.1.10.0/24 ip unconfigured
eth1.12 network 10.1.12.0/24 ip unconfigured
eth1.50 network 10.1.50.0/24 ip unconfigured

Looking at ovs-vsctl show on the network node I see this

```
    fa0de79d-1eda-4ca4-8ba0-e61d3f56fa48
Bridge br-int
    fail_mode: secure
    Port "tape4578535-95"
        tag: 1
        Interface "tape4578535-95"
    Port int-br-data
        Interface int-br-data
            type: patch
            options: {peer=phy-br-data}
    Port "tapeeeea50e-6f"
        tag: 1
        Interface "tapeeeea50e-6f"
    Port br-int
        Interface br-int
            type: internal
    Port "tap528061f5-ee"
        tag: 2
        Interface "tap528061f5-ee"
    Port patch-tun
        Interface patch-tun
            type: patch
            options: {peer=patch-int}
    Port "tap21864535-77"
        tag: 2
        Interface "tap21864535-77"
Bridge br-ex
    Port "tapb91a4a0c-6e"
        Interface "tapb91a4a0c-6e"
    Port br-ex
        Interface br-ex
            type: internal
    Port "tap7d397af3-c3"
        Interface "tap7d397af3-c3"
    Port "eth1"
        Interface "eth1"
Bridge br-tun
    fail_mode: secure
    Port "gre-0a010116"
        Interface "gre-0a010116"
            type: gre
            options: {df_default="true", in_key=flow, local_ip="10.1.1.21", out_key=flow, remote_ip="10.1.1.22"}
    Port patch-int
        Interface patch-int
            type: patch
            options: {peer=patch-tun}
    Port br-tun
        Interface br-tun
            type: internal
Bridge br-data
    fail_mode: secure
    Port br-data
        Interface br-data
            type: internal
    Port phy-br-data
        Interface phy-br-data
            type: patch
            options: {peer=int-br-data}
ovs_version: "2.5.0"
```

I may be barking up the wrong tree but I think part of my issues is that br-ex is attached eth1 not eth1.50. I learned via another post that I am supposed to use juju to edit openstack components on an Autopilot install however I can't figure out where in the neutron charms for gateway or openvswitch to change that. I set and commited br-ex:eth1.50 for the data-port on the neutron-gateway charm but that didn't seem to have an effect.

Can someone point me in the right direction as where I configure this and if there is more configuration that is needed to ensure that the router and floating IP exit via vlan 50 to the physical network.

I've read this blog
http://www.opencloudblog.com/?p=654

and these openstack articles
http://docs.openstack.org/liberty/networking-guide/scenario-provider-ovs.html

however they refer to components that aren't being used by Autopilot deployment, mainly the ML2 plugin and mainly aim to directly connect instances to the physical network. I just want the external interface of the router and floating IPs accesible via VLAN 50 on the physical network.

Comment: I successfully tested connectivity by moving the eth1 interfaces to ports that are untagged members of vlan 50, so I know everything else is in working order. I just need to get br-ex associated with vlan 50 instead of the root port.